# Modify winform control property from different class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Form project with 1 form (FormMain) and 3 user controls (TitleScreen, MainScreen, and InGameMenu) acting as different screens. Contained in MainScreen is a Label, lblDate, the Text property of which needs to be modified elsewhere in the project (TitleScreen and InGameMenu), but because I can't make it static I can't make a static public property to access it. I heard that events might get the job done but I have no idea how to do it. Please help me figure out how to modify lblDate.Text from another class. I don't care how it gets done at this point. This is driving me crazy.

In ScreenReferenceHolder.cs

```
class ScreenReferenceHolder
{
    #region Field Region

    private static FormMain formMain;

    private static UserControls.TitleScreen titleScreen;
    private static UserControls.MainScreen mainScreen;
    private static UserControls.InGameMenu inGameMenu;

    #endregion

    #region Property Region

    public static FormMain FormMain
    {
        get
        {
            if (formMain == null)
                formMain = new FormMain();
            return formMain;
        }
    }

    public static UserControls.TitleScreen TitleScreen
    {
        get
        {
            if (titleScreen == null)
                titleScreen = new UserControls.TitleScreen();
            return titleScreen;
        }
    }

    public static UserControls.MainScreen MainScreen
    {
        get
        {
            if (mainScreen == null)
                mainScreen = new UserControls.MainScreen();
            return mainScreen;
        }
    }

    public static UserControls.InGameMenu InGameMenu
    {
        get
        {
            if (inGameMenu == null)
                inGameMenu = new UserControls.InGameMenu();
            return inGameMenu;
        }
    }
```

in Program.cs

```
        Application.Run(ScreenReferenceHolder.FormMain);
```

in FormMain.cs

```
    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Controls.Add(ScreenReferenceHolder.TitleScreen);
        this.Controls.Add(ScreenReferenceHolder.MainScreen);
        this.Controls.Add(ScreenReferenceHolder.InGameMenu);

        ScreenReferenceHolder.MainScreen.Visible = false;
        ScreenReferenceHolder.InGameMenu.Visible = false;
    }

    #endregion
```

I have tried putting this in MainScreen.cs but nothing can access it.

```
    public string LabelDate
    {
        get { return lblDate.Text; }
        set { lblDate.Text = value; }
    }
```

Finally, in MainScreen.Designer.cs is the label

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.lblDate = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    }
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblDate;
```

Comment: How are you trying to read that property? Could you show the code inside one of your controls that fails to read the property?

Comment: Making everything `public static` like this is bad practice. You shouldn't make a habit of it.

Comment: This method was suggested to me in another question I asked. How should I go about this while still being able to have the access I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your posted code, you should be able to access LabelDate in MainScreen from anywhere using:

```
ScreenReferenceHolder.MainScreen.LabelDate
```

Comment: Yea, that was the problem.... such stupid mistakes.